# How do you call a function from within the factory using a string in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

I have some logic I would like to wrap up into an AngularJS factory so I can use angular's dependency injection.  Since the logic is dynamic I don't necessarily know what is available to call ahead of time.  What I have is a string representing the name of the function to call.  I know I can do something like `window["someFunctionName"]()` to run a function with a string but since everything is wrapped up in a factory I'm not sure how to get reference to the factory to call it. ex.  `sampleFactory["someFuncitonName"]();`

The only way I have found to run the function is using `eval("someFuncitonName()")`.  Obviously I would like to avoid using eval if I can.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('testApp')
  .factory('testFactory', function (someData) {

    // User defined code that was wrapped up in a factory
    function foo() {
        someData.amount = 5;
    }
    // End dynamic code

    return {
      funcRunner: function(functionName) {
        testFactory[functionName]();
      } 
    };

  });
```

In the controller the user would run something like this `testFactory.funcRunner("foo");`.

Is there some way to do something along these lines `testFactory[functionName]();`?  Is there some better way of doing this?  Thanks for your help.

**Update:**  Since the code in the comment is user defined I have no way of knowing nor do I have any control over how the code in the comments is written.  I don't want to force any restrictions on the user.  Therefore I can expect very little.

Comment: Are you just trying to return the someData.amount?

Comment: Is there any way you can generate the code such that instead of  defining the function as function foo() {} it is defined as this.foo = function () {}?

Comment: I should have been more clear.  The code is user defined so I won't have control over how/what is written.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

from what I have read there isn't a way to do this.  Its just how javascript works.  There is no way to call the foo function via a string.  The foo function would have to be part of an object to call it with a string.  I just wanted to confirm there aren't any clever ways around this.

Comment: I don't like it either Mr. -1 but there just isn't any way to call the foo function as a string in JS.  I have had to change my approach because of this fact but I would love to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Try this approach:

```
angular.module('testApp').factory('testFactory', function () {
    var service = this;
    this.foo = function() {
        someData.amount = 5;
    }

    return {
        funcRunner: function (functionName) {
            service[functionName]();
        }
    };
});


function Ctrl($scope, testFactory) {
    $scope.click = function () {
        testFactory.funcRunner("foo");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes.  That would work but would require that I enforce rules for how the code must be written.  I don't really want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $parse to parse the string and call a function.   Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/WeirdAlfred/Lsfwtb96/

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

//inject the $parse service into your controller, service, factory, etc.
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$parse', myController]);

function myController($scope, $parse) {
    //setup a function on scope that will receive the 
    //string that you wish to execute as a function.
    //Note: this function doesn't need to be on scope, it's just there so 
    //we can call it with button clicks.   This could be any function
    //on a controller, service, factory, etc.
    $scope.buttonClick = function (someStringValue, useAngularParse) {
        alert('The string value passed in from the button click:  ' + someStringValue);

        //the parse service takes a string and converts it to a function call
        //the format for the command is:
        //$parse(inputString)(objectOfAvailableFunctions, objectOfParams);
        $parse(someStringValue)(internalFunctions);
    }

    //this provides a list of available functions for the 
    //$parse to call when it evaluates the given string.
    var internalFunctions = {
        catsSuckEggs: catsSuckEggs,
        dogsRock: dogsRock
    }

    //some random function that you want to make available via a string
    function catsSuckEggs() {
        alert('My cat is worthless!');
    }

    //some other random function that you want to make available via a string 
    function dogsRock() {
        alert('I wish my wife would let me have a dog!');
    }
}
```

Here's some quick markup that enables the buttonClick and passes in the string.

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <h2>Do you like Cats or Dogs?</h2>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="buttonClick('catsSuckEggs()')">Cats</button>
        <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="buttonClick('dogsRock()')">Dogs</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: this would require that end users create an internalFunctions obj. and keep it up to date as they modify their code.  I was trying to prevent the user from having to care about the environment.  I was hoping there was a sneaky JS trick i wasn't aware of.  Thanks though. :)